Why won't this code allow me to hide a pdf file "inside" of a png file using Ruby?
I'm trying to hide a file called "hello_world.pdf" inside of an image file "kitten.png". The code I'm using is:
original_image_file = File.read("kitten.png")
hidden_file = File.read("hello_world.pdf")
output_file = "output.png"

separator = "*----------[#{hidden_file}]----------*"
output = [original_image_file, separator, hidden_file]

File.open(output_file,'wb') do |f_out|
    output.each do |f|
        f_out.puts f
    end
end

I'm supposed to be able to click on output.png and see the original image (kitten.png), but then if I change the file extension to .pdf and click on output.pdf, it's supposed to show me hello_world.pdf.
However, when I click on output.png or output.pdf, in both cases it says it can't display the image or pdf. Do you have any idea why this is not working correctly?

"if I change the file extension to .pdf and click on output.pdf, it's supposed to show me hello_world.pdf" – Which version of the PDF specification are you referring to? There's like 28 of them.

Your "separator" contains an entire copy of the hidden file's content.  Also, there's no reason to expect any PDF reader to recognize your file, since it starts with a PNG image at the beginning.  A PNG reader might recognize the file if it's designed to ignore junk at the end, or it might not!

You don't need a separator. Simply add 2 files back to back, in different ways, MAY work in different viewers, but not all. So here the cat is a PDF in Firefox or a PNG in MS Edge but no assurances they can work in Acrobat as it is not an ISO PDF format.


Some viewers may see one as both !

Others may explain why.

So overall the one that is fooled easiest is a web browser such as Firefox and PDFjs, as it's an image viewer that also converts PDF into images:

